# Не работает Redux Devtools для server-rendering react-приложения

Tags: reactjs, redux

Redux Devtools не работает server-rendering react-приложения

Всё делал по инструкции, но ничего не получается https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools

Уже второй месяц сижу и не могу запустить нормальное приложение на react, такое, какое мне нужно - с server-rendering, isomorphic, нормальными css и т.д.! А не такое примитивное, как в официальной документации. Тупейшая технология! Просто тупейшая! Не получается просто взять и нормально начать что-то делать! Каждый раз что-то везде отваливается!